# Prove that $\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)=-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, legendre-polynomials

The question is from [The number of solutions of $ax^2+by^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is $ p-\left(\frac{-ab}{p}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398200/the-number-of-solutions-of-ax2by2-equiv-1-pmodp-is-p-left-frac-abp/398245#398245)

And I wonder how to prove the following equation although someone gives the trick:
\begin{split}
\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)=-1
\end{split}
Here is the trick:using$\left(\frac{y^*}{p}\right)$ instead of$\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)$

$y^*$  is the inverse of $y$ modulo $p$

Comment: The use of the trick is explained in comments under that answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much.  I noticed it but at first I didn't get it , now I konw how to solve it :)

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer:

We can replace $\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)$ with $\left(\frac{y^*}{p}\right)$ such that:

\begin{split}
\left(\frac{y}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{y^*}{p}\right).
\end{split}

We can easily verify it by using primitive root.

When $y = 0$ there is no inverse, so we ignore the first term of  $\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)$.

So we have:

\begin{split}
&\sum_{y^*=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y^*}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)\\
&=\sum_{y^*=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1+y^*d}{p}\right)\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1+yd}{p}\right).
\end{split}

Because we know that:
\begin{split}
\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1+yd}{p}\right) = 0
\end{split}

[Legendre symbol: Showing that $\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{am+b}{p}\right)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/legendre-symbol-showing-that-sum-m-0p-1-left-fracambp-right-0)

So it lacks the first term, that is $\left(\frac{1}{p}\right) = 1$, and we can get:
\begin{split}
&\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y+d}{p}\right)\\
&=-1.
\end{split}

There is a better way I think:

\begin{split}
\left(\frac{y(y+d)}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{y(y+dyy^\ast)}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{y^2(1+dy^\ast)}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{1+dy^\ast}{p}\right)
\end{split}

from[$\left( \frac{1 \cdot 2}{p} \right) + \left( \frac{2 \cdot 3}{p} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{(p-2)(p-1)}{p} \right) = -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552521/left-frac1-cdot-2p-right-left-frac2-cdot-3p-right-cdot?rq=1)